# collision response between line and circle not always bouncing off correctly using refletion formula

Tags: javascript, vector, 2d, physics

For my collision response i used the reflection formula r = d - 2(d.n)n however the bounce only works if the ball hits the left hand side of the line, if it hits the right hand side it goes straight though instead of bouncing off, my code is

```
var dn = pCircle.getDirectionVector().dotProduct(pLine.getLineVector().normalise());
var dn2 = 2 * dn;
var dn2n = pLine.getLineVector().normalise().multiply(dn2);
var result = pCircle.getDirectionVector().subtract(dn2n);
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

Turns out the value i was using for d and n were the wrong way round it should be the following instead

```
var dn = pLine.getLineVector().dotProduct(pCircle.getDirectionVector().normalise());
var dn2 = 2 * dn;
var dn2n = pCircle.getDirectionVector().normalise().multiply(dn2);
var result = pLine.getLineVector().subtract(dn2n);
```

The ball now bounces off the right hand side of lines however sometimes it will still change direction but will pass through the line.

**Edit 3**

I wasnt clear on what result is suppose to be, result is suppose to be the new position that the circle goes toward after the collision. Once i have this result vector i call a methord inside my player object which does the vector passed in - player position normalises it then times by speed this resulting vector is set as the circles direction vector. This is so that when i request next animation frame the circle obj calculatates new position which takes the stored direction vector and adds that to its current position.

Comment: What is `result` supposed to represent?

Comment: Result is suppose to be the new vector for the circle which is used when re drawing the canvas to determine the new position to draw at.

Comment: I'll edit my question to include more detail

Comment: So... If the initial velocity of the circle is perpendicular to the line, then `dn` will be zero, `dn2n` will be the zero vector, `result` will be the vector of the line, which means... either I'm misunderstanding what these variables represent, or your math does not match real physics very well.